# New Static Library has build error "libtool exited with code 1"

Tags: xcode4, static-libraries

I created a new static library in my iOS project and now I'm getting the build error

`Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1`

How do I go about debugging this?

Comment: I would really love to know the answer to this also.

Comment: I get /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: -dynamic not specified, -all_load invalid

Comment: My problem was that I've deleted some shared files that this project also referenced, and I did not notice that those were in red since they were in a folder down in the hierarchy, and xcode did not warn me, instead it throw me this error with libtool. so I just deleted the missing files, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To see the actual output and not just the error message, try building your target or scheme with `xcodebuild` from command line.

I had a problem with the same error message. In my case, I couldn't build for the simulator, but it worked find when building for the device. The output from `xcodebuild` confirmed that Xcode could not set the proper architecture to build for the simulator.

Long story short, it turned out that one build setting was corrupted. The `Mach-O Type` setting in the *Linking* category was set to `Relocatable Object File` for some reason. I switched it back to `Static Library` and the error disappeared.